# Difficulty extracting IMDb ratings by demographic (with IMDbpy)

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I would like to collect the IMDb rating details by demographic (gender, age group).

When I try to use the get_movie_vote_details module in imdbpy, my output is empty. 
Here is my code:

```
 import imdb

 i =  imdb.IMDb(accessSystem='http')

 movie = i.get_movie('0780504')

 print(movie)

 votes = i.get_movie_vote_details('0780504')

 print(votes)
```

and here is the output:

`print(m)`

> Drive

`print(votes)`

> {'charactersRefs': {}, 'data': {}, 'namesRefs': {}, 'titlesRefs': {}}

As you can see, the "votes" output is a little off. Is there a way I can extract rating details using imdbpy?

Comment: I tires the same code and it looks like an error with the library: "'AttributeError: 'DOMHTMLPlotParser' object has no attribute '_useModule'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
Call stack:
Message: '%s: unable to gather refs: %s'
Arguments: ('DOMHTMLPlotParser',)'
Drive", strangely prints the title but not the other data

Comment: @oetoni : that bug is already fixed in the repository version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to call the *.get_movie_XYZ(...)* methods directly: they are used internally to update a Movie instance using the *IMDb().update(...)* method.

For example:

```
import imdb

i = imdb.IMDb(accessSystem='http')

movie = i.get_movie('0780504')
i.update(movie, 'vote details')
print(movie.get('mean and median')
```

If you want to know all the available info sets, call `i.get_movie_infoset()`; to see which keys of a Movie instance were added when a given info set was updated, use the `movie.infoset2key` mapping.

For more information, refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/blob/master/docs/README.package.txt).

Regarding the format of the data, this code:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
m = ia.get_movie('0780504', 'vote details')
print('median', m.get('median'))
print('arithmetic mean', m.get('arithmetic mean'))
print('number of votes', m.get('number of votes'))
print('demographics', m.get('demographics'))
```

will output something like this:

`median 8
arithmetic mean 7.8
number of votes {1: 8626, 2: 4135, 3: 5762, 4: 9264, 5: 17595, 6: 39440, 7: 84746, 8: 133331, 9: 98870, 10: 75737}
demographics {'imdb staff': {'rating': 7.8, 'votes': 36}, 'aged under 18': {'rating': 8.5, 'votes': 844}, 'non us users': {'rating': 7.8, 'votes': 250586}, 'top 1000 voters': {'rating': 7.6, 'votes': 739}, 'males aged 45 plus': {'rating': 7.4, 'votes': 24213}, 'aged 45 plus': {'rating': 7.4, 'votes': 28779}, 'aged 18 29': {'rating': 7.9, 'votes': 183217}, 'us users': {'rating': 8.0, 'votes': 71299}, 'aged 30 44': {'rating': 7.7, 'votes': 181063}, 'males aged under 18': {'rating': 8.5, 'votes': 705}, 'males aged 30 44': {'rating': 7.8, 'votes': 152988}, 'females aged under 18': {'rating': 7.9, 'votes': 133}, 'males aged 18 29': {'rating': 8.0, 'votes': 148749}, 'females aged 45 plus': {'rating': 7.4, 'votes': 4004}, 'imdb users': {'rating': 7.8, 'votes': 477506}, 'females aged 18 29': {'rating': 7.6, 'votes': 32575}, 'females': {'rating': 7.6, 'votes': 65217}, 'males': {'rating': 7.9, 'votes': 341617}, 'females aged 30 44': {'rating': 7.5, 'votes': 25465}}`

Comment: Thanks @Davide. I now understand the syntax better and have used it to pull other detailed information (budget, gross, etc). I will stay tuned for the next update when *hopefully* the ratings feature will be fixed.

Comment: @driskerr the parser should be fixed, now. If you can, please test it (and if you find the answer satisfying, accept it).

Comment: hmm this is exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately, when I reinstall imdbpy and I run the code exactly as written and I get the following output: `median None
arithmetic mean None
number of votes None
demographics None`

Comment: @driskerr : did you use the Github version? I've not packaged/released it, yet (will be done in some weeks: I want to fix some stuff)

Comment: hallejuah! it works now! I thought I had reinstalled the Github version, but I guess I messed up somewhere. Thank you for addressing this for me